# CKEditor5 Medialibrary insert add custom classes

Tags: media

For my text-format i have "drupal media insert" in my toolbar, when choosing an image to insert there are options to align the image, i.e "align left break text" it will add a data-align attribute and in the frontend add a class ".align-left"

Is there a way to add further classes to the figure element without patching the core files?

Right now I am using a behaviour for that, but that feels like a weird ducktape

e.g

`$(once('setLegacyImageAlignClasses', 'figure.align-left', context)).addClass('embedded-entity content-image content-image--medium pullout pullout--left');`

what would be the correct way to add further custom classes? (D10.1, ckeditor5)